# Can't have CNAME for domains root, using noip to point to static host

Tags: domains, dns, dynamic-dns

I'm aware that I'm unable to have a CNAME as the domains root under the ruling 3.6.2 of RFC 1034, however I'm using noip to point to a static hostname.

Currently I have www pointed to my noip static hostname, and i've got an A record pointing to my IP address, the only problem is that i need that A record to point to my static hostname, otherwise what's the point in using noip? I may as well set all my records to point to my IP.

Is there a way for me to perhaps 301 redirect mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com?

My domain registrar is Heart Internet and as far as i've seen, they only offer me the choice to redirect my www.mydomain.com to something else.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit off your question, but also useful if someone else runs into this issue. DNSMADEEASY has a service they call AName records, which can support dynamic ip addresses for A records. They do this by doing an ip lookup from a Cname record. This is useful for Cloud Based hosting where your Ip address might change.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to host your web site on a dynamic IP address?

If that is the case, your dynamic DNS provider will need to handle your DNS.  They will need to update your A record as your IP changes.

So you will likely need to have a paid account with a dynamic DNS provider and then you will want the following records.

`domain.com` will be set dynamically by your dynamic DNS provider.

Then setup a `CNAME` to map `www.domain.com` to `domain.com.

I am not certain you can do this with No-IP's free service.

If you must pay for a dynamic DNS service, you may want to call your network provider and just get a static IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I use Amazon AWS Route 53 for DNS.   They have a solution to this problem.   They have an [alias](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) DNS record type.  From their documentation:

- **CNAME Records** - You cannot create a CNAME record at the top node of a DNS namespace, also known as the zone apex. For example, if you register the DNS name example.com, the zone apex is example.com.
- **Alias Records** - You can create an alias resource record set at the zone apex.

An alias record works much like a CNAME record from a setup perspective.  You specify a host name where you want it to resolve.   On the lookup side, the alias record works like an A record.   Amazon's DNS server return an IP address.  They do the lookup internally.

Amazon created this functionality because their load balancers are only addressable by host name because the IP addresses can change abruptly.   Before this functionality, it was not possible to have an AWS load balancer handling HTTP requests for the root domain.

This functionality would work for your situation too.   Amazon does [charge for these services](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/).  Expect to pay in the range of $1 per month if you use their DNS for your domain.

[Frank](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/2379/frank) says in the comments that [DNS made easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/)  also has AName records with similar functionality.  They charge about $30 per year.